# How to use typescript's discriminated unions with object instead of switch/if statements

Tags: typescript, type-inference, discriminated-union

I am using a discriminated union, but instead of branching with conditional statements, I want to use object mapping (`calculationHandlers` object in the following code snippet). Here's what it looks like:

```js
const sumThreeNumbers = (one: number, two: number, three: number) => {
    return one + two + three
}

const multiplyTwoNumbers = ({ one, two }: { one: number, two: number }) => one * two

const calculationHandlers = {
    sum: sumThreeNumbers,
    multiply: multiplyTwoNumbers
} as const
 
type SumCalculation = {
    type: 'sum',
    input: Parameters<typeof sumThreeNumbers>
}

type MultiplyCalculation = {
    type: 'multiply',
    input: Parameters<typeof multiplyTwoNumbers>
}

type Calculation = SumCalculation | MultiplyCalculation

const handleCalculation = (calculation: Calculation) => {
    const calculate = calculationHandlers[calculation.type]

    return calculate(...calculation.input)
}
```

[Link to typescript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=28&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCuBbAKgCwE4FNMDkkCNN0IYBeGACnEwC4YwCiAaGKAdxDocUPRagzYujdAEoyAPhgBvALAAoGEphYo8dGBjUYAalYddrQZgUBfBQtCRYieABsoASwAOdgJ7IOeHkRLkK0lpgmPwGpnSB1MI%20fPqc9CIwpuKkUtoAVHEW8lbQMMAAhnbA9gVO4AASBWAAJna%20ZDIKynBIdAgoxt68EEzNyrYOLu50g06uHl4iEGYwBSS5UM0KUG7OmDAAykgAwkUldmWO4I1yisqr63QA5B3XfedKjmDO8FB0AAoF6AWImFC%20AA8l0wIAAZq1OlhcNMJGZsiCYABZezjdx7YqlcqachnFogm5jYZue79J4vN6fb6-f5AkHgmBEiaeEDdXxw%20TmeQrNYbDEHI4ncjbRD8rHHTQAH2RqOJYsO2OyixgqGqdUw8sFOMohUxColdE12JSUjxymVuoFAMalvFlTV9WIAG1bfrwAA6EEAXWyLVU6k0rrKmAo7rDQex7uerygonh3PkQA)

Typescript complaints about arguments passed to `calculate` function, however, mismatching arguments doesn't seem to be possible here.

Comment: Yeah, typescript can't track relation between types of `calculate` and `calculation.input`